# Illegal G-code when trying to print

Tags: g-code, simplify3d, wi-fi

I recently upgraded to [Simplify3D](https://www.simplify3d.com) version 5.  With this version, I can now print over WiFi to my Qidi X-Pro.  I run an Eero mesh network and the printer is about 6 feet from the router.

I tried printing a model with this version over WiFi and received the following error on the Qidi console:

```
Illegal gcode in line: xxxx, P_4, T_10470103!
```

On a second attempt, I received:

```
Illegal gcode in line xxxx, P_$, T10470000!
```

The same models print correctly if saved to a USB stick first and then inserted into the printer.  I've been in contact with Simplify3d support, but, they can't recreate the problem.

Has anyone encountered this problem?  Do you know of a fix?

Comment: My experience with Qidi technical support, via email, has been quite good. It takes a couple of days between exchanges, but they may have some assistance for you. I was able to request and receive an S3D profile for my X-Max.

Comment: Instead of the update, could you please post this as the answer. How  strange this answer might sound, it helped you, it might help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran another test.  This time I used the USB device that came with the printer.  The print finished without errors.  I'm not sure why using a different USB device would impact the WiFi printing.

Note: I have some suspicions that using a quality setting of High may have actually caused the problem.